# firebase dynamic links app preview page IOS flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using firebase_dynamic_links 2.0.6 and when I open the dynamic link in the safari browser it shows first app preview page is the[image]first is there any way to redirect to the link without preview page at first.

Comment: Never used dynamic links before, but it does say at the bottom of the picture, "you can bypass the app ..." can you show the whole ? text maybe someone can help you with that.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews
but i use flutter package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it in DynamicLinkParameters there is

navigationInfoParameters:
NavigationInfoParameters(
forcedRedirectEnabled: true),
this bypass page preview in ios.